# Is there a google-reader like rss reader which I could install to my own host

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

and access it with browser?

Like fever rss reader but from opensource world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some FLOSS web-based feed readers that I know of:

### Perl

- [Urchin](http://urchin.sourceforge.net/)

### PHP

- [Feed on Feeds](http://feedonfeeds.com/)
- [Gregarius](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gregarius/)
- [Lilina](http://getlilina.org/)
- [lylina](http://lylina.sourceforge.net/)
- [Monkeychow](http://www.shokk.com/blog/articles/tag/monkeychow)
- [Newswall](http://newswall.mayoco.de/index_e.php) (CC licenced)
- [Rnews](http://rnews.sourceforge.net/)
- [Rsslounge](http://rsslounge.aditu.de/?hl=en)
- [Tiny tiny rss](http://tt-rss.org/) (see [Alin Andreis answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/175307/82665) for features)

### Python

- [NewsBlur](http://www.newsblur.com/)
- [Planet Planet](http://www.planetplanet.org/) (it's more for a planet, but could work as personal feed aggregator, too)
- [Rawdog](http://offog.org/code/rawdog.html)

Comment: Great answer! Which of them is keeps unread items till one reads them (not the river-of-news style) and has the simplest installation as I'm not very advanced user and installation guidelines of NewsBlur make me sad

Answer (score 1):

There are many RSS readers available for Linux. You already have one installed - Thunderbird. I use it to read my rss feeds.

Another popular RSS reader is [RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org).

Comment: Yes, I know it, but my question was about hosted solutions, so I want my own google reader, on my own host.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tiny Tiny RSS](http://tt-rss.org/redmine/).

Features:

- Server-side application, user only needs a web browser

  Supports RSS, RDF, Atom feeds using Magpie and SimplePie libraries

  Easy setup and configuration

  Streamlined interface using AJAX

  Free software, licensed under GNU GPL

  Authentication for reading protected feeds (e.g. LiveJournal
  friend-only posts)

  Supports feed aggregation, keyboard shortcuts, OPML import/export,
  multiple and single user operation, mobile devices,
  internationalization, detecting and filtering duplicate articles,
  podcasts, article scoring, content filtering, JSON-based API, Twitter
  feeds, feed sharing between instances, and more...

  Official Android client (work in progress)

A demo can be found here: http://tt-rss.org/demo/tt-rss.php